# Select box populated from database invisible text

Tags: php, html, mysql, drop-down-menu

My problem is not connecting my select box to my database but getting the info to show.... It connects and i can see the boxes for the amount of items i have in my database table but there is no text in any of them. My database table is .CSV im not sure if that could cause a problem?

Here is my code: In my code i will just put in dummy_.... (What ever item) instead of the real thing.

```
<?php
require_once('auth.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<link href="styles/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<head>

</head> 
<body>
    <form id="dropdown">        
        <?php
            mysql_connect("localhost", "repaiami_member", "zmozmozm2083") or die("Connection Failed"); 
            mysql_select_db("repaiami_member")or die("Connection Failed");
        ?>
        <?php 
            $query = "SELECT * FROM lighting"; 
            $result = mysql_query($query); 
        ?>
        <table width="450px;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select id="dropdown_description" name="select1" class="ui-select selBox">
                        <?php
                            while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $line['field'];?>"> <?php echo $line['field'];?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form> 
</body>  
</html>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you tried a `var_dump($line)` or `print_r($line)` to see what's inside the row?

Comment: Can you put up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with the generated markup instead of php code?

Comment: does your lighting table have a column named `field`?

Comment: There is a description field and watt's field... Also how would i use the print_r($line) ?

Comment: Description column and watts column sorry not field.

Comment: This is the link to the page http://form.repairme.co.za/lighting_form.php There is a dropdown... Tell me if that helps!